# Codeigniter input type text array validation

Tags: php, codeigniter

HTML View form

```
<div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <input type="text" name="keywords[]" class="form-control input-sm" tagchecker="alphanumeric" value="<?php echo set_value('keywords[]'); ?>" placeholder="Tag or Keyword" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <input type="text" name="keywords[]" class="form-control input-sm" tagchecker="alphanumeric" value="<?php echo set_value('keywords[]'); ?>" placeholder="Tag or Keyword" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <input type="text" name="keywords[]" class="form-control input-sm" tagchecker="alphanumeric" value="<?php echo set_value('keywords[]'); ?>" placeholder="Tag or Keyword" />
           </div>
          <div class="col-lg-4">
                <input type="text" name="keywords[]" class="form-control input-sm" tagchecker="alphanumeric" value="<?php echo set_value('keywords[]'); ?>" placeholder="Tag or Keyword" />
        </div>
          <div class="col-lg-4">
                <input type="text" name="keywords[]" class="form-control input-sm" tagchecker="alphanumeric" value="<?php echo set_value('keywords[]'); ?>" placeholder="Tag or Keyword" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <input type="text" name="keywords[]" class="form-control input-sm" tagchecker="alphanumeric" value="<?php echo set_value('keywords[]'); ?>" placeholder="Tag or Keyword" />
            </div>
        </div>
```

In my controller

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('keywords[]', 'Keyword or Tags', 'xss_clean|alpha_dash');
```

Actual problem,
    All above input text's for Keywords array are not mandatory (No required rule applied in controller), but if user enters something other than `alpha_dash`, Codeigniter should display validation error for that field only. It should not display error for blank fields.

If I write a callback, how can I Manage `return FALSE and error message for particular text box`?

How can i achieve this?  any suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think by adding index to keywords you can do that think. but you need to specify separate validation for each input type.

```
<div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <input type="text" name="keywords[0]" class="form-control input-sm" tagchecker="alphanumeric" value="<?php echo set_value('keywords[0]'); ?>" placeholder="Tag or Keyword" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <input type="text" name="keywords[1]" class="form-control input-sm" tagchecker="alphanumeric" value="<?php echo set_value('keywords[1]'); ?>" placeholder="Tag or Keyword" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <input type="text" name="keywords[2]" class="form-control input-sm" tagchecker="alphanumeric" value="<?php echo set_value('keywords[2]'); ?>" placeholder="Tag or Keyword" />
           </div>
          <div class="col-lg-4">
                <input type="text" name="keywords[3]" class="form-control input-sm" tagchecker="alphanumeric" value="<?php echo set_value('keywords[3]'); ?>" placeholder="Tag or Keyword" />
        </div>
          <div class="col-lg-4">
                <input type="text" name="keywords[4]" class="form-control input-sm" tagchecker="alphanumeric" value="<?php echo set_value('keywords[4]'); ?>" placeholder="Tag or Keyword" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <input type="text" name="keywords[5]" class="form-control input-sm" tagchecker="alphanumeric" value="<?php echo set_value('keywords[5]'); ?>" placeholder="Tag or Keyword" />
            </div>
        </div>
```

In Controller.

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('keywords[0]', 'Keyword or Tags', 'xss_clean|alpha_dash');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('keywords[1]', 'Keyword or Tags', 'xss_clean|alpha_dash');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('keywords[2]', 'Keyword or Tags', 'xss_clean|alpha_dash');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('keywords[3]', 'Keyword or Tags', 'xss_clean|alpha_dash');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('keywords[4]', 'Keyword or Tags', 'xss_clean|alpha_dash');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('keywords[5]', 'Keyword or Tags', 'xss_clean|alpha_dash');
```

i think it will solve your problem.